How to select a visual block with the mouse
Old Vimmer and wannabe Doom Emacs user here. I'm trying to set up my init.el/custom.el file so that I can select a visual block (a.k.a rectangle or column) in evil mode with my mouse in combination with Ctrl or Alt.
It's a simple feature I use quite a lot in Vim, and it's one of the few things that keeps me from going all in with Emacs. I tried more than once to tweak a solution that works for non-evil column selection, for example this one:
Enable Emacs column selection using mouse
but couldn't get it done. Any help would be much appreciated.

You can select a rectangle region by pressing control and meta and left mouse button
 when dragging the mouse pointer.
(This works well when using vanilla GNU Emacs.  I didn't test in Doom Emacs.)

Thanks. I didn't know that, but unfortunately, it doesn't work with evil-mode on. evil-visual-block is different than Emacs's native implementation of column selection -- and also different from CUA-rectangles.
